# Glass Card.toRemoteViews() returns null

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

Using the Google Glass GDK, I'm trying to put together a simple app that displays / updates a live card. In my Service, I have the following method:

```
private void publishCard(Context context) {
    Card updatedCard = new Card(context);

    updatedCard.setText("Foo");
    updatedCard.setInfo("Bar");

    RemoteViews cardViews = updatedCard.toRemoteViews();
    if (cardViews == null)
        Log.e(TAG, "Appears to happen every time!")

    // Then do some other stuff that fails because of a null RemoteViews
}
```

As you can see above, the null check seems to fail every time. Any idea why that might be?

My thought is that I'm calling this and passing in a Service as the context rather than an Activity, and maybe you're not supposed to do that? If that were the case, though, how would you be able to update a Live Card? I am capable of constructing a RemoteViews from an XML, but being able to use a Card would simplify things a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That method is not currently implemented; you can follow [issue 268](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=268) on our issue tracker if you want to keep track of the progress.

For now, you will have to create your own layout XML and use that to create the `RemoteViews`.

Comment: Well, that's a lot simpler answer than I expected. :) I can deal with that.